# is php5-curl what I want?

Tags: server, package-management, software-recommendation, php, curl

I have an NGINX web-server, with php-fpm.  I would like to install curl, but I’m not sure that php5-curl is the right package for my server. Should I be concerned? is there a more appropriate package?  If I just install curl, with that include php libraries?

Comment: php5-curl is the right Package, curl is more secure and its also perfect for security reason. You can also look _file_get_contents_ and _fopen_ 
but i recommend to Install: _sudo apt-get intall php5-curl_

Comment: Some hosting companies also disable the opening of URL with fopen or file_get_contents for security reasons.

Comment: good  to know, but i don’t have those issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install curl *PHP extension* then php5-curl is the package you want. If you want to install just `curl` as in the command then the package name is `curl`.

Please learn about the basic package commands as: `apt-cache show <package>` and `apt-cache search <pattern>` and more.